# No album icon on Google Photos

Tags: nexus-5, google-plus-photos

I am trying to follow the [these instructions](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113885?hl=en) to create albums in my Google+ Photos app,
but when I am selecting photos I have the share icon but not the album icon.

I don't know why this is happening. I tried uploading from my computer and the albums work great. How can I create them on Android? I'm running Android 5.0.